# Comparing the first field of two files and out putting the entire record for those fields of both files if the fields match

Tags: awk, field, matching

I have two files, par1.txt, par2.txt. I want to look at the first field or column of both files, compare them and then if they match print the record or row where they are matched.

Examplefiles:

par1.txt

```
ocean;stuff about an ocean;definitions of oeans
park;stuff about parks;definitions of parks
ham;stuff about ham;definitions of ham
```

par2.txt

```
hand,stuff about hands,definitions of hands
bread,stuff about bread,definitions of bread
ocean,different stuff about an ocean,difference definitions of oceans
ham,different stuff about ham,different definitions of ham
```

As for my output I want something like

```
ocean:stuff about an ocean:definitions of oeans
ocean:different stuff about an ocean:difference definitions of oceans
ham:different stuff about ham:different definitions of ham
ham:stuff about ham:definitions of ham
```

The FS in the files are different, as shown in the example. 
The output FS doesn't have to be ":" it just can't be a space.

Comment: I presume the order of the lines is not guaranteed, so `ocean` may appear anywhere in `par1.txt` and anywhere in `par2.txt`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Based on your comments, I believe you have more than 2 files and that the files have sometimes commas and sometimes semicolons as separators and that you want to print any number of lines which have matching first fields as long there are more than one with that first field. If so, I think you want this:

```
awk -F, '
   {
     gsub(/;/,",");$0=$0;              # Replace ";" with "," and reparse line using new field sep
     sep="";                           # Preset record separator to blank
     if(counts[$1]++) sep="\n";        # Add newline if anything already stored in records[$1]
     records[$1] = records[$1] sep $0; # Append this record to other records with same key
   }
   END { for (x in counts) if (counts[x]>1) print records[x] }' par*.txt
```

**Original Answer**

I came up with this:

```
awk -F';' '
   FNR==NR {x[$1]=$0; next}
   $1 in x {printf "%s\n%s\n",$0,x[$1]}' par1.txt  <(sed 's/,/;/' par2.txt)
```

Read in `par1.txt` and store in array `x[]` indexed by first field. Replace the comma in `par2.txt` with a semicolon so that the separators match. As each line of `par2.txt` is read, see if it is in the stored array `x[]` and if it is, print the stored array `x[]` and the current line.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Just one question, what if say, I wanted to do this for more than two files at a time?

Comment: Use `cat` to join files together first, i.e. `cat file6 file7 file8 file9 > bigfile, then use `bigfile` as the second input to `awk`.

Comment: hmm it seems to only spit the records out in groups of 2.

Comment: That's because the question said there were two files originally so it stores all the records from the first file and then, as each record is read from the second file, it checks if it has already got a stored definition and if it has, prints both. Maybe you need to restate the question to work with a single file containing all your files concatenated together as the single input file? I'm not sure if that is what you want either though.

Comment: Maybe your differing field separators and the number of files are all a distraction. Let's suppose you actually have files `par1.txt`, `par2.txt` ... `par37.txt`. If you do `tr ';' ',' < par*.txt | sort > big.txt`, can you now say what needs to be done to `big.txt`?

Comment: Yea, I apologize. I had assumed if it would work for two files then it should work the same way for any number of files. I used cat to make one bigfile and changed the field separator in this bigfile to only be ";" . So then would have to been done now is look at the first field for the entire file and print out all records with the same string for it's first field. So like my first example of par1.txt and par2.txt that would all be one file and the output would be the same except the occurrences of the string isn't limited to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=":" '
{ $1 = $1 }
NR==FNR { lines[$1] = $0; next }
($1 in lines) { print lines[$1] RS $0 }
' FS=";" par1.txt FS="," par2.txt
```

**Output:**

```
ocean:stuff about an ocean:definitions of oeans
ocean:different stuff about an ocean:difference definitions of oceans
ham:stuff about ham:definitions of ham
ham:different stuff about ham:different definitions of ham
```

**Explanation:**

- Set the Output field separator to `:`. If you want space delimited you dont need to set `-v OFS`.
- `$1=$1` helps us reformat the entire line so that it can take the value of `OFS` while re-constructing.
- `NR==FNR` reads the first file in to array.
- When we process the second file, we look for first column in our array. If is present we print the line from array and the line from second file.
- `FS=";" par1.txt FS="," par2.txt` is a technique where you can specify different field separator for different files.

---

If you have repeatitive first column in both files and would like to capture everything then use the following. It is similar logic but we keep all lines in array and print at the end.

```
awk -v OFS=":" '
  { $1 = $1 }
  NR==FNR {
      lines[$1] = (lines[$1] ? lines[$1] RS $0 : $0);
      next
  }
  ($1 in lines) {
      lines[$1] = lines[$1] RS $0;
      seen[$1]++
  }
  END { for (patt in seen) print lines[patt] }
' FS=";" par1.txt FS="," par2.txt
```

Comment: +1! You could move the `$1=$1` to a common block at the front of the script if you like. `awk -v OFS=':' '{$1=$1} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{print a[$1] ORS $0}' FS=';' file1 FS=',' file2`